# renewcommand for description

Tags: macros, environments, description

I have a document with many `\description` environments. All of them are defined like this:

```
\begin{description}[leftmargin=2.5cm,style=sameline]
    \item[\texttt{foo}] bar 
    \item[\hspace{7mm}\texttt{sub}] inner
\end{description}
```

How can I use `\renewcommand` (or something similar) to not always have to write `[leftmargin=2.5cm,style=sameline]`
and also have the argument of `\item` automatically be in `\texttt` and optionally be preceded by some space `\hspace{7mm}`?

Other solutions are also greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `newlist` from [the `enumitem` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem) to define your custom styles.

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{MyDescription}{description}{1}
\setlist[MyDescription]{leftmargin=2.5cm,style=sameline, font=\texttt}

\newcommand*{\IndentedItem}[1][]{\item[\hspace{7mm}#1]}%

\begin{document}\noindent
Manually specified:
\begin{description}[leftmargin=2.5cm,style=sameline]
    \item[\texttt{foo}] bar 
    \item[\hspace{7mm}\texttt{sub}] inner
\end{description}

\noindent
Using \verb|MyDescription|:
\begin{MyDescription}
    \item[foo] bar 
    \IndentedItem[sub] inner
\end{MyDescription}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks awesome! Going to use it - Thank You! One more question, I don't know if it's possible: I would like to replace `\item[\hspace{7mm}sub] inner` with something like `\item2[sub] inner` and have the same result. Is it possible? Thank You for your superfast help!

Comment: @jlordo: Not recommended to have numbers in the macro names, btu can be done.  Have updated solution to define a `\IndentedItem` macro.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a new environment:

```
\newenvironment{mydescription}{\begin{description}[leftmargin=2.5cm,style=sameline]} 
                              {\end{description}
```

Comment: This looks like it solves the first part of my problem. Thank You! Do You also have a hint for the default formatting of my `\item` items?

Comment: I'd go with *peter grill*'s solution.